# Create a Mask with Nodes where There are Shadows (Cycles)

Tags: node-editor, shadows, procedural

I'm creating a Procedural Earth Shader, and I'd like to add city lights on the dark side of the Earth. I could just use a gradient texture, and map it to the dark side of the Earth, and use that as the factor for where the lights are. But I'd like to be able to rotate the Earth and the Sun Light, and have the city lights only show in the shadow area. Is there any way to do that with nodes? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe the second half of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222746/35559)?

Comment: I know this wasn't part of your question, just to let you know: my solution is based on a Sun object with a _Track To_ constraint pointing at Earth, since sun lamps are infinite lights always only pointing in one direction. I did this to avoid using a point lamp but still have the sun always shine on Earth no matter where one of the objects is. Because the _Shader to RGB_ node doesn't work in Cycles there is no way to directly determine which side is lit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Cycles* I used the following setup for my "Earth + Sun" model. First of all, I've got an *Empty* parented to my Earth object. The *Empty* has a *Track To* constraint, target is the sun object and *Target Axis* is -Z, so it's pointing away from the sun.

In the Earth material I use the *Object* output of a *Texture Coordinate* node with the *Empty* as object. A *Separate XYZ* gives the Z value. The "sunny side" of the Earth is equal or below zero and the shadow side is greater than zero. This I use as multiplier for the emission. Of course you can use a *Color Ramp* or other methods for sharper transitions or whatever. This is just to give the basic idea, you can always tweak here and there.

[image]

These are the objects:

[image: earth + sun]

This is the Z output I get from the *Separate XYZ* node as multiplier:

[image: separate xyz]

And my final node setup of the Earth material for this example (my real Earth model of course uses more complex textures etc):

[image: earth node setup]

Here are some examples how to tweak the transition from light to shadow. The above image of the Z output looks simply black on the one side, but since these are the object's texture coordinates the black part isn't simply 0 but goes from 0 in the middle to -1 on the outer edge. A *Map Range* node mapping the -1 to 1 range on a 0 to 1 range colored by a ramp shows this:

[image: map range normalize]

To make the transition sharper you can shrink down the range by changing the *From Min* and *From Max* values, e.g. to -0.1 and 0.1:

[image: shrinked map range]

Or maybe you want to shift the city lights a little bit to the sunny side (people already turning on their lights as the daylight fades?), than you can do that by shifting the *From Min* and *From Max* values more to the negative side, like -0.3 and -0.1:

[image: map range shift]

I guess you can imagine a lot more variations of manipulating this.

Comment: Thank you! Just one question, when I move the sun, it doesn't rotate automatically to be pointing at the earth like your file does. How can I do that?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it! I forgot to add the constraint to the Sun object. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @RyanKingArt My mistake, I should have put that in the answer... maybe I'll edit it later. Actually when I first did this a while ago I wanted to use the sun's texture coordinates instead of adding an extra empty, but I couldn't get this to work. So I guess there's a new tutorial coming? ;)